# Can I prevent somebody from joining a public group?

Tags: steam

Today some jerk joined the Arqade group on Steam and started spamming people with links to a lookalike phishing site. You know, like this but with "store.steampowered.com" instead of "twitter.com":

> [image]
>
> <sup>Image from the [OpenDNS Phishing quiz](http://www.opendns.com/phishing-quiz/). Hint: this one is a phish.</sup>

Now, I've kicked him from the group and flagged his account, but... it's a public group! Anybody can join. We'd rather not change that and still keep him out.

Is kicking sufficient? What else can I do?

Comment: And they keep joining :(

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with gaming...

Comment: @BlaXpirit Steam has absolutely nothing to do with Gaming?

Comment: This is a question for meta, but I feel like this should be off-topic too.  Troubleshooting steam so you can play your games is one thing; but moderating a steam group just seems too-far removed from actually playing games to be on-topic.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You know what I think. Just like we allow all questions about consoles - _and the web services thereof_ - I don't see the problem with questions about Steam web services

Comment: Why the hell does this have four close votes? This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: @Fluttershy I don't agree with the close votes. But those are probably because it [fails "the second test"](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5675/4797).

Answer (score 3):

You can't ban people from groups permanently, unfortunately.

What you can do is to report people via their profile and Steam will have a look at it.

You can also ban him from the groupchat.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, nothing stops him from joining again.

Is he spamming on community page/forums, Steam Group chat, or individual chat?
For page, maybe there is some mute or some way to remove his permissions, but for chats, you can only block him.

Comment: Individual chat, so far.